# React-Admin Typescript error : Uncaught TypeError: calling a builtin Promise constructor without new is forbidden

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript, react-tsx

I'm trying to fetch data by a hook but I don't know why I have no TS error and when I'm launching the code I have a console error which says "Uncaught TypeError: calling a builtin Promise constructor without new is forbidden"

```
export const JobsList = () => {
  const [companies, setCompanies] = useState(Promise<any>);

  useEffect(()=>{
    DataProvider.getList("companies").then(res => setCompanies(res.data));
  })
  // const companies = await DataProvider.getList("companies"); 
  // const isSmall = useMediaQuery((theme : any) => theme.breakpoints.down("sm"));
  return (
    <List filters={JobFilterBuilder(companies)}>
```

My component `JobList` can't be async. And my `DataProvider.getList` return a promise so I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need to assign a `Promise` to a state variable.

```
DataProvider.getList("companies").then(res => setCompanies(res.data));
/* this line will fetch the data from the API 
and set the response data into the state variable,  
most probably the `res` here would be a JSON and 
`res.data` could be an array or object */
```

So you can write

```
const [companies, setCompanies] = useState<any>();
```

but if you know the type of response you're receiving or maybe you can check it with the network tab in the browser, or in your console by adding a console log or from a tool like `postman` and build your own `type` or `interface` for the response and use it as the state type would be the better solution with `typescript`.

As an example let's assume you receive something like this as the response from your API call

```
[
  {
    "companyId": 1,
    "companyName": "Star company"
  },
  {
    "companyId": 2,
    "companyName": "Bravo company",
  },
]
```

you can type safe the state by define the type like this

```
type CompanyType = {
   companyId: number,
   companyName: string
}

//and assign this as your state type
// we use `CompanyType[]` here since we receive an array of CompanyType
const [companies, setCompanies] = useState<CompanyType[]>();
```

hope you get the idea, happy coding... !

**EDIT**
you can get an idea of how to properly create a Promise in JS, and how Promises work by read [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_promise.asp)

Comment: First thanks for you answer ! Very useful ! I'll try to apply it